# How do I get an APP ID for Facebook on my web site?

Tags: authentication, web, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-login

First of all, my simple purpose is to add a Facebook login button to my web site.  So I go to the login button description.

I must be thick headed, but I cannot get an APP ID.  Under the "Authentication" writeup it says, "The JavaScript SDK requires that you register your website with Facebook to get an App ID (or appId)."  Clicking on "Register Your Website" takes me to the APPS page. And since the login button is indicated under "Websites", I click that and it just takes me to another page that says I must register my website.  I am ready to pull out what hair I have left.

What am I missing?  Do I have to create a "new" app?  I can't call it login since apparently that already exists.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an app here:

http://developers.facebook.com/

Click on Apps -> Create New App

Give the app a name etc the you will need to add your websites URL into the Website section.

Comment: What if I don't have a website of my own, can I just give a random website ?